# Update query is not working in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a update query in my android application. But its not working properly. When clicking the button for updating the application stops working. The code is as follows-

```
update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String feched_name = show_name.getText().toString();
            String get_std_for_update=id_search.getText().toString();
            String get_new_name = id_update.getText().toString();

            if(feched_name.matches("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Student selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                    else {
                        if(get_new_name.matches("")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Name is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }
                        else{
                            stdDB.execSQL("Update student set name = "+get_new_name + "where id = "+get_std_for_update);    
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student's name has been updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                        }
                    }


            }

           });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the query below with the existing one :

```
stdDB.execSQL("Update student set name = '"+get_new_name + "' where id = "+get_std_for_update);
```

Mark the single quote around the name and the space.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats it. I forgot to add single quotes. Its working now. Thank you.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it was helpful to you, it will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
stdDB.execSQL("Update student set name = '"+get_new_name + "' where id = "+get_std_for_update);
```

or

```
stdDB.execSQL("Update student set name = \""+get_new_name + "\" where id = "+get_std_for_update);
```

Please note I added quotes and also I added a space after your where clause.